# Unable to unmarshall ZoneDateTime with XMLAdapter(Error thrown)

Tags: java

Trying to pass a string that looks like this "2019-04-01T10:00:00.000-0500". I created an ZonedDateAdapter class that extends the xmlAdapter class(See below). I am parsing the string and then adding the UTC zone. The parsing seems to be ok but once the request finishes it throws an exception.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class ZonedDateAdaptor extends XmlAdapter<String, ZonedDateTime> {
   @Override
   public ZonedDateTime unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {

       return LocalDateTime.parse(v, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
   }

   @Override
   public String marshal(ZonedDateTime v) throws Exception {
       return v.toString();
   }
}
```

This ends up throwing an error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.time.ZonedDateTime.<init>()
   at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350)
   at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2554)
   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory.tryGetDeclaredConstructor(ClassFactory.java:137)
   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(ClassFactory.java:106)
   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.createInstance(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:285)
   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:702)
   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:188)
   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:577)
   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:246)
   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:180)
   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:415)
   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:394)
   at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:887)
   at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$200(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:103)
   at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$3.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:926)
   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:924)
   at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:744)
   at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:172)
   at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:109)
   at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Not sure where to go from here all examples i see are with localdateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ZonedDateTime.parse` and use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters` on the field also

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
return ZonedDateTime.parse(v, formatter);
```

Comment: May be problem is somewhere else. Are you use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters` for link the adapter

Comment: Thank yes I was missing the annotation on one of the fields.